# undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass. Instance variable doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<tbody>
    <% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= article.title %></td>
      <td>Some description</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
</tbody>
```

I defined an instance in controller, but I cannot get it to work in my html.erb.

```
def index
        @articles = Article.all
 end
```

When I change @articles to Article.all - it works.

Can anyone tell me why the instance variable doesn't?

Thanks

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'pages#home'
  get 'about', to:'pages#about'
  resources :articles, only: [:show, :index]
end




 class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def index
        @articles = Article.all
    end

    def create
        @article = Article.new(params.require(:article).permit(:title, :description))
        if @article.save
            flash[:notice] = "Article was created successfully"
            redirect_to @article
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def new 
        @article = Article.new
    end
end
```

Comment: Is the right controller called?

Comment: it is in ArticlesController

Comment: Just to confirm, your ERB code is in `app/views/articles/index.html.erb` and your controller code is in `app/controllers/articles_controller.rb`, with standard routing set up?

Comment: the code above seems correct, probably the other factor , can you upload your routes.rb file and detail controller for article

Comment: this is the exact path
@widjajayd
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'pages#home'
  get 'about', to:'pages#about'
  resources :articles, only: [:show, :index]
end

Comment: Code seems correct. Can you show the whole controller? 
Whats the url you called?

Comment: @SimonFranzen I added controller. My url localhost:3000/articles

Comment: Can you confirm what @magni- was asking? Your ERB code is in `app/views/articles/index.html.erb` and your controller code is in `app/controllers/articles_controller.rb`?